# Разделение королевства.Встроенные структуры данных. Python

Tags: python

## Разделение королевства

Королевство Флатландия имеет вид бесконечной двумерной плоскости. В королевстве находятся n замков. Для более удобного составления карт в Флатландии была введена Декартова система координат. Известно, что **i**-й замок находится в точке с координатами **(xi+0.5, yi+0.5)**, где **xi**, **yi** — целые числа. Местоположения всех замков попарно различны.

На старости лет король решил разделить на карте королевство между своими сыновьями прямыми, параллельными осям координат. Если прямая параллельна оси Ox, то y координата у всех точек на прямой должна быть целым числом, иначе x координата у всех точек должна быть целым числом. В обоих случаях соответствующие целые координаты по модулю не должны превышать 2⋅10^9. При этом Его величество хочет, что бы после разделения королевства любые два замка оказались бы в различных частях.

Помогите королю разделить королевство, используя не более чем n−1 прямых. У любой пары прямых должно быть не более одной общей точки.

### Входные данные

В первой строке задано целое число **n** *(1≤n≤100000)* — количество замков в королевстве. В следующих n строках записано по два числа **xi** и **yi****(−10^9≤xi≤10^9, −10^9≤yi≤10^9)** — целые части координат замков.

### Выходные данные

В первой строке выходного файла выведите количество используемых прямых. В следующих строчках выведите сами прямые, по одной в каждой строке. Если прямая параллельна оси Ox, то выведите символ "y", а затем через пробел y координату всех точек на этой прямой, иначе выведите символ "x", а затем через пробел x координату всех точек на этой прямой.
Примеры

***Ввод***

4

0 2

0 3

1 2

1 3

***Вывод***

2

y 3

x 1

Мой код не проходит по времени. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
n = int(input())
 
a = list()

b = list()

x = set()

y = set()

for i in range(n):

    xx, yy = map(int, input().split())

    a.append([xx, yy])

    b.append([yy, xx])

a.sort()

b.sort()

for i in range (n - 1):

    if a[i+1][0] == a[i][0] and a[i+1][1] > a[i][1]:

        y.add(a[i][1] + 1)

    else:

        x.add(a[i][0] + 1)

print(len(x) + len(y))

for i in y:

    print("y " + str(i))

for i in x:

    print("x " + str(i))
```

Comment: Вот бы люди придумали давать переменным понятные имена. b это что?

Comment: Решение: Отсортируем замки по x координате, между
каждой парой соседних замков проведем прямую.
Посмотрим на замки, которые имеют одинаковую
координату по x.
Для каждого такого x отсортируем замки по y
координате. Проведем прямую между каждой
парой соседних замков.
Заметим, что при таком разделении, количество
прямых не превышает n − 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, n):
    if x[i] == x[i-1]
        горизонтальная прямая
    else
        вертикальная
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
a = list()
x = set()
y = set()
for i in range(n):
    xx, yy = map(int, input().split())
    a.append([xx, yy])
a.sort()
for i in range(n - 1):
    if a[i + 1][0] == a[i][0] and a[i + 1][1] > a[i][1]:
        y.add(a[i][1] + 1)
    else:
        x.add(a[i][0] + 1)
print(len(x) + len(y))
for i in y:
    print("y " + str(i))
for i in x:
    print("x " + str(i))
```